# AngularJS - Using indexOf inside ng-repeat to show/hide values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, ng-hide

I have a `JSON` file that contains a bunch of data:

myData.JSON:

```
{
"Addresses": {
    "AddressList": [
        {
            "HouseNumber": 201,
            "Street": "Victoria Lane",
            "Postcode": "SW1 8ES"
        },
        {
            "HouseNumber": 10,
            "Street": "Allen Close",
            "Postcode": "NG2 3TD"
        },
        {
            "HouseNumber": 57,
            "Street": "Thomas Street",
            "Postcode": "DR12 6TE"
        },
        {
            "HouseNumber": 57,
            "Street": "Old Lister Street",
            "Postcode": "OL4 5TH"
        },
        {
            "HouseNumber": 45,
            "Street": "Milk Round Street",
            "Postcode": "MK6 4HG"
        },
        {
            "HouseNumber": 102,
            "Street": "Jersey Quarter Avenue",
            "Postcode": "DR12 6TE"
        },
        {
            "HouseNumber": 845,
            "Street": "MR HAPPY STREET",
            "Postcode": "MR3 0FJ"
        }
    ]
}
```

Im trying to show a `div` if a match on the returned value from Street is found via a indexOf

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="address in Addresses.AddressList">
    {{ address.HouseNumber }}, {{ address.Street}}, {{ address.Postcode }}
    <div ng-show="address.Street.toLowerCase().indexOf('MR HAPPY STREET') == 0">
        MR HAPPY STREET WAS FOUND
    </div>
    <div ng-show="address.Street.toLowerCase().indexOf('Milk Round Street') == 0">
        Milk Round Street WAS FOUND
    </div>
</div>
```

This doesnt seem to work. Can you perform such `indexOf` via an `ng-show`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you compare 2 strings which are not the same: after use `toLowerCase()` function your string `Milk Round Street` looks like `milk round street`. So `indexOf()` will return `-1`.
That's why you need to compare 2 strings in lower case, such as:

```
<div ng-show="address.Street.toLowerCase().indexOf('mr happy street') == 0">
```

or:

```
<div ng-show="address.Street.toLowerCase().indexOf(('MR HAPPY STREET').toLowerCase()) == 0">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
<div ng-repeat="address in Addresses.AddressList">
    {{ address.HouseNumber }}, {{ address.Street}}, {{ address.Postcode }}
    <div ng-show="showByJs(address,'MR HAPPY STREET')">
        MR HAPPY STREET WAS FOUND
    </div>
    <div ng-show="showByJs(address,'Milk Round Street')">
        Milk Round Street WAS FOUND
    </div>
</div>
```

in controller write

```
    $scope.showByJs=function(address, indexofWord){
    if (address.Street.toLowerCase().indexOf(indexofWord) == 0)
    {
       return true;
    }else
     {
       return false
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check with lowercase of `"MR HAPPY STREET"` and `"Milk Round Street"` because you'r trying compare with lowercase of `address.Street` .

```
<div ng-repeat="address in Addresses.AddressList">
    {{ address.HouseNumber }}, {{ address.Street}}, {{ address.Postcode }}
    <div ng-show="address.Street.toLowerCase().indexOf(('MR HAPPY STREET').toLowerCase()) == 0">
        MR HAPPY STREET WAS FOUND
    </div>
    <div ng-show="address.Street.toLowerCase().indexOf(('Milk Round Street').toLowerCase()) == 0">
        Milk Round Street WAS FOUND
    </div>
</div>
```